# HIDE ROWS in EXCEL by CONDITION

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

So i am building a pricing sheet through excel and have about 1,000 rows of line items.

I need to allow the user to check the boxes they want to see and then display only those boxes via the use of a form control button (or whatever is better here).

The end result is to get 20-30 items from this master list to display for a price sheet printout for a specific vendor.

I am not familiar with VBA code, but have enough experience with other areas where I can execute and edit a code if given a starting point and simple instructions.

I have inserted checkboxes into the first column, and set the linked cells to display true false in the 2nd column. all i need is to write a macro to hide if false (checkbox unchecked) in column 2 and get it to process the macro in under 12 minutes.

Any help or suggestions here are greatly appreciated!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a very simple loop, and shouldn't take anywhere near your 12 minute time limit. When "Hide Rows" is clicked, run the following code:

```
    'This will make it so the screen doesn't "flicker" while the code is running
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

For Each cell In Range("B4:B16").Cells
        If cell.Value = False Then
            Rows(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

    'Turn screen updating back on or Excel will appear "frozen"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Just remember to change the Range in the For statement to your actual Range, and you should be all set!

Comment: ha. i guess the 12 minute mark was more of sarcasm on my end. I have several sheets in this workbook, do I need to do anything specific to ensure it is only pulling this sheet? Otherwise I will update the range to the 1,000+ rows and see what happens!!

Comment: Indeed! Just change Rows(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True to Rows(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = False. :)

Comment: "do I need to do anything specific to ensure it is only pulling this sheet?"

Yes! My example was just quickly done, but to make sure it's only doing the sheet you want, do one of two things. Either put Sheets("Sheet Name"). before any calls to Range, or Activate the sheet you are editing just before calling the loop.